# C# WinForms BindingList & DataGridView - disallowing EDIT prevents creation of a NEW row? How can I address this?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, bindingsource

Regarding my use of a DataGridView with BindingList, I was to disable editing current rows, but allow adding new rows.  The issue I have is that when I disallows edits, this seems to prevent one from adding a new row item, as when you table into the cell for this new row it does not seem to allow editing???

Know how to get around this?   Section of my code below:

```
   BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
   bList = new BindingList<Customer>();
   bList.AllowNew = true;
   bList.AllowEdit = false;

   // Fill bList with Customers
   bList.Add(new Customer("Ted"));
   bList.Add(new Customer("Greg"));
   bList.Add(new Customer("John"));

   bs.DataSource = bList;
   dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than fight the source, perhaps ask the `DataGridView` to officiate:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.CurrentCellChanged += delegate 
{
    DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
    bool readOnly = row == null ||
        row.Index != dataGridView1.NewRowIndex;
    dataGridView1.ReadOnly = readOnly;
};
```

(and don't set `AllowEdit` on the list)